# How to post object with file to backend? 415 error. c#, Angular

Tags: c#, angular, typescript

How can I upload file?

So my model looks like this:

```
public class HtPermitOrderRequest
{
    public IFormFile FormFile { get; set; }
    public List<string> Woids { get; set; }
    public string Io { get; set; }
    public string Contractor { get; set; }
    public string NavisionWo { get; set; }
}
```

Service

```
requestPermitsForOrders(model: HtPermitOrderRequest){
     return this.http.post(baseUrl + '/api/mass-actions/request-permits', model);
}
```

calling service like this:

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("formFile", result.formFile[0]);

this.dataToSend = {formFile: formData, io: result.io, woids: woids, contractor: result.contractor, navisionWo: result.navisionWo};
console.log(this.dataToSend);
this.configurationService.requestPermitsForOrders(this.dataToSend).subscribe(res => {
});
```

This is error that I am getting: [image]

I tried to make request with postman and it was ok so I guess I am doing something wrong in angular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to send json. But you  need to send it with formdata.

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("formFile", result.formFile[0]);
formData.append("io", result.io);
formData.append("woids",woids);
formData.append("contractor", result.contractor);
formData.append("navisionWo",  result.navisionWo);

this.configurationService.requestPermitsForOrders(formData).subscribe(res => {
});
```

accept formdata in function

```
requestPermitsForOrders(model: any){
     return this.http.post(baseUrl + '/api/mass-actions/request-permits', model);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, makes sense. It's working! Thank you very much, I lost alot of time on this but it was actually stupid mistake.